# In Laravel, how to set up a relationship for a "likes" table? Also, how to include that information in a query?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationships

I have three tables: **users**, **ideas**, and **ideas_likes**.  The ideas_likes table looks like:

```
ideas_likes
------------
id        primary key
user_id   foreign key
idea_id   foreign key
liked     boolean
```

There's already a one-to-many relationship set up between users and ideas.  It looks something like this:

```
class User extends Ardent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    protected $table = 'users';

    public function ideas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Idea');
    }   

}
```

Similarly, the idea model looks like this:

```
class Idea extends Ardent {

    protected $table = 'ideas';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

}
```

My first question is: How do I create the IdeaLike model?  And once that is finished, using Eloquent, how do I retrieve all liked ideas for a user?

===========================================================================

Lucasgeiter's updated solution worked great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there's no need to create an `IdeaLike` model. You just need a [many-to-many relationship](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#many-to-many)

#### User

```
public function ideas(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Idea', 'ideas_likes')->withPivot('liked');
}
```

#### Idea

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'ideas_likes')->withPivot('liked');
}
```

(By adding `withPivot` I tell Laravel that I want to have the `liked` column from the pivot table included in the result)

#### Usage

```
$user = User::find(1);
$likedIdeas = $user->ideas()->where('liked', true)->get();
```

By the way: You don't need to specify the `$table` if it is the plural of the model name.

### Update

It looks like you actually really do need both, a one-to-many and a many-to-many relation.

So your final relations would look like this:

#### User

```
public function ideas(){
    return $this->hasMany('Idea');
}

public function liked(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Idea', 'ideas_likes')->withPivot('liked');
}
```

#### Idea

```
public function likes(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'ideas_likes')->withPivot('liked');
}

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

(I just chose names for the relations that made kind of sense to me. You can obviously change them)

#### Usage

Liked ideas by a certain user: (`id = 1`)

```
$ideas = Idea::where('user_id', 1)->whereHas('likes', function($q){
    $q->where('liked', true);
})->get();
```

Comment: Oh, interesting!  Let me give it a shot.  I'll accept your answer if everything goes well.  Thanks so much!

Comment: Sure. Just leave a comment if you need any help ;)

Comment: This worked great.  I have one follow up question, if you wouldn't mind.  I'll add it to my original posting.

Comment: Well since you have a pivot table and a many-to-many relationship, the `user` relation returns a collection. So to get the individual users you would need to loop over the result of the relation

Comment: Hmm, I think I understand.  But there really is only a one-to-many relationship between users and ideas.  Users cannot share the same idea.  I'm trying to fetch all ideas and include the associated user information so I can output it in my loop.  I've updated my question to show my foreach loop.  Am I thinking about this wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68101/discussion-between-clone45-and-lukasgeiter).