# In Laravel / Eloquent, how to fetch items along with 'liked' or 'disliked' status

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, relationships

This is an extension to a previous question that I asked, which was how to set up a [relationship between users, ideas, and 'likes'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27747373/in-laravel-how-to-set-up-a-relationship-for-a-likes-table-also-how-to-inclu).  A user can create multiple ideas.  Any user can 'like' or 'dislike' any idea.

As mentioned in the previous post, here are my relationship in Laravel:

**User**

```
public function ideas(){
    return $this->hasMany('Idea');
}

public function liked(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Idea', 'ideas_likes')->withPivot('liked');
}
```

**Idea**

```
public function likes(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'ideas_likes')->withPivot('liked');
}

public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

My 'ideas_likes' table looks like:

```
ideas_likes
------------
id        primary key
user_id   foreign key
idea_id   foreign key
liked     boolean
```

I have a webpage that lists ideas from various users.  Only an authenticated user can reach this page.  Next to each idea is a *like* and *dislike* button.  When the *like* button is clicked, an entry is added to the ideas_likes table with the 'liked' boolean set to true.  When the *dislike* button is clicked, and entry is added with the 'liked' boolen set to false.

When a user *dislikes* an idea, that idea should no longer show up in the list for that user.  If the user *likes* an idea, then the idea will be highlighted in the list.

When displaying the ideas in my view, I'll be looping through them like so:

```
@foreach ($ideas as $idea)
  <div class="idea">
    <h1>{{ $idea->title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ $idea->description }}</p>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

However, as noted, I'll want to highlight ideas that have been 'liked' by the user viewing the list.  Maybe it would look something like this:

```
@foreach ($ideas as $idea)
  <div class="idea@if($idea->liked) highlight@endif">
    <h1>{{ $idea->title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ $idea->description }}</p>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

Plus, I want the idea author's username (which is not necessarily the same as the logged in user) shown too:

```
@foreach ($ideas as $idea)
  <div class="idea@if($idea->liked) highlight@endif">
    <h1>{{ $idea->title }}</h1>
    <p>{{ $idea->description }}</p>
    <p>{{ $idea->user->username }}</p> <=== SOMETHING LIKE THIS
  </div>
@endforeach
```

Previous to introducing the concept of 'likes' to my application, my query for gathering the idea and user information looked like:

```
$ideas = Idea::with('user')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

That was returning a list of all ideas, plus their associated user information.  Now, however, it gets trickier.  I want all of the ideas, plus their associated user information (whomever posted it), except for those ideas disliked by the currently authenticated user, and also highlighted if they were liked by the authenticated user.  Phew!

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This takes care of the eager loading and filters out the ideas the current user disliked.

```
$ideas = Idea::with('user', 'likes')->whereDoesntHave('likes', function($q){
    $q->where('user_id', Auth::id());
    $q->where('liked', false);
})->get();
```

Now you can add an [accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) to create a dynamic `liked` property. In `Idea`:

```
public function getLikedAttribute(){
    $user = $this->likes->find(Auth::id());
    return $user != null && $user->pivot->liked == true;
}
```

You can use it just like you had it in your question. `$idea->liked`. Note that you should eager load `likes` to use this accessor. Otherwise for every idea an additional query will be run to fetch `likes` when you access `->liked`.

### Update: More efficient

I found a way to make it a bit more efficient and without a loop for each idea. However I find it a bit more ugly. To be able to eager load the data I had to create a new relation.

```
public function likedByCurrentUser(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'ideas_likes')
                ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
                ->where('liked', true)
                ->selectRaw('COUNT(*) > 0 AS liked');
}
```

And here's the rewritten accessor:

```
public function getLikedAttribute(){
    return !! $this->likedByCurrentUser->first()['liked'];
}
```

You see, the loop is gone!

Finally you need to eager load the new relation. Here's the example:

```
$ideas = Idea::with('user', 'likedByCurrentUser')->whereDoesntHave('likes', function($q){
    $q->where('user_id', Auth::id());
    $q->where('liked', false);
})->get();
```

Alternatively you can add `likedByCurrentUser` to the `with` array in the model so it will be eager loaded all the time.

```
protected $with = array('likedByCurrentUser');
```

### Update 2

Looking now at my old solution, I believe this can be done a bit nicer (and hopefully it will be working correctly too)

Relation:

```
public function likedByCurrentUser(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'ideas_likes')
                ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
                ->where('liked', true);
}
```

And the accessor:

```
public function getLikedAttribute(){
    return ! $this->likedByCurrentUser->isEmpty();
}
```

The usage stays the same as above.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to remove `likes` from `with` and do `$this->likes()->find(Auth::id());` in the accessor since it doesn't look like he needs the likes? Although both don't seem to be too good performance wise, don't they?

Comment: No since then it will run a query every time `liked` get's accessed (and that will be done in a loop...)

Comment: But how fast is `find()` on the collection?

Comment: I'm sure it's faster than running a db query. But I agree it's not an ideal solution. Let me know if you have a better idea

Comment: Yep it's deffinitely better than a query but it's still a [loop per idea](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.php#L21).

Comment: If a better solution would require a change in my database schema, I'm all ears.  Technically Lukas's solution works.  However, I would recommend adding '->get()' to the end of $ideas = Idea::with.  As a novice, this threw me for a moment.

Comment: @clone45 Oops forgot the `get()`. I'm just working on something more efficient... I'll let you know when I have come up with something

Comment: returning `false` from a relationship (which is what you do calling it as *dynamic property* in your example) will throw exception `Relationship must return Relation ...`

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk I never called the relation a dynamic property but you're right. What would you suggest for catching a not logged in user?

Comment: You're doing it in the accessor. I don't think it belongs to the Eloquent model to decide whether a user is authorized to see anything or not.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk That's true. I just noticed that even with `Auth::id()` returning void when no user is logged in it won't blow up the whole thing and just no records will match ergo: `liked == false` which I suppose is the desired result.

Comment: Fantastic.  Works great.  In my situation, this page will only be visible to authenticated users, so the Auth::id() should never return void.  Thanks so much!

Comment: @clone45 You're welcome. And even if there was no authenticated user, liked would just be false. Nothing to worry about ;)

Comment: Sorry it's been a while.  I found an issue in this solution (the 'more efficient' one).  Only the first "liked" idea in the database returns true when calling $idea->liked in the view.  Any ideas?

Comment: @clone45 No not off the top of my head... I'll look into it and tell you if I find something

Comment: I'll keep testing, but that appears to have done it!  I seriously owe you a beer.